# Clear TextFormField error message before disabling

Tags: flutter

So I have a TextFormField and a Checkbox. The Checkbox controls whether the TextFormField is enabled or disabled by setting the `enabled` parameter of the TextFormField.

The problem I am having is that if the TextFormField has an error message, the error message persists even after the `enabled` parameter is set to false. This is very confusing to the users. How can I clear the error message whenever I disable the TextFormField?

```
ListTile(
    leading: Checkbox(
        value: _enabled,
        onChanged: (value) =>
            setState(() => _enabled = value!)),
    title: TextFormField(
      enabled: _enabled,
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return "Please enter text";
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    ),
  )
```

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the error

Comment: Added just now.

Comment: if you disable the textFormFiled it will remove the error by default.   I might need full sample widget from scaffold body what actually cause the trouble here. using flutter 3.10.3

Comment: The actual widget is way more complicated than the cut out section here. If the error is removed by disable by default, I think I will peel down the structure and see what is causing the problem. Let me get back to you.

Comment: Well, I created a test widget with that exact snippet and it still doesn't clear the error text when disabled. Perhaps that's the default behavior in the current flutter (3.10.5)?

Answer (score 0):

You can make validator to check if Field is disabled

```dart
if (value?.isEmpty ?? true && _enabled) {
  return "Please enter text";
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your listtile in a form widget and after changing _enabled value, form state needs be reset, here is a simple code:

```
 Form(
          key: key,
          child: ListTile(
              leading: Checkbox(
                value: enabled.value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  enabled.value = value!;
                  key.currentState!.reset();
                  setState((){});
                },
              ),
              title: TextFormField(
                enabled: enabled.value,
                validator: (String? value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return "Please enter text";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          
        ),
```